# Can I display connected controllers on HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I'm coding an interface using HTML/CSS/JS, and I want to know if it's possible to display the connected controllers on PC in the page. Showing like this on top https://forums.launchbox-app.com/uploads/monthly_2019_05/2.png.deb01c501df34f22090a5715785f7392.png

Comment: how did your implementation of the interface turn out?

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how to bind controls to shortcuts, for example a combination of two keys for the Y in the controller etc ..

Comment: Sounds interesting. Would  you be able to share your code so we could take a look at it together?

Comment: I'm still adjusting stuff but I will definitely share with you my progress tomorrow if not today.

Answer (score 0):

Sure is! In your searches you want to focus on the word gamepad instead of controller.
You are going to be checking for a new DOM event gamepadconnected which must be a GamepadEvent type of event. Check out the [W3C Gamepad Page](https://www.w3.org/TR/gamepad/) for all the details on how to.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I was looking for. And I have to agree with you in the use of the word gamepad instead too.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the instruction on how to connect the controller and capture events here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Gamepad_API/Using_the_Gamepad_API.

If you need more help with the implementation, add the code you work with to your question.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will update my post later if I have difficulties with implementation :)